# Adding navigation button below a Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, navigationbar

I have a very simple Slider made using Jquery and I want to add navigation under the slider. It may be dot boxes, anything is fine.

Please help me in this. Below are the codes

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
            $('.sp').hide();    
            $('.active').show();

                $('#button-next').click(function(){

                $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                               if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
                    $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
                    }
                    else{
                    $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
                    }
                $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
                $('.sp').fadeOut();
                $('.active').fadeIn();


                });

                   $('#button-previous').click(function(){
                $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                       if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
                    $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
                    }
                       else{
                $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
                       }
                $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
                $('.sp').fadeOut();
                $('.active').fadeIn();
                });
            });
    </script>

    <div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="sp" style="background: blue;">akjdfalfkdj</div>
        <div class="sp" style="background: yellow;">akjdfautlfkdkjkhkj</div>
    </div>
    <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
    <div id="button-next">next</div>
    <div id=""nav"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HsEne/15/

Comment: why are you using own script instead of ready made script [plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)?

Comment: I have not use plugin as I am working for a dedicated cms where plugin cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You tried something like that

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/HsEne/642/)

code added in your jquery code.

```
var n = $( "#slider div" ).length;
var i=1;

while(n>i)
{
    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>"+i+"</div>" ) );
    i++;
}
```